# How to use threads in lazarus?

Tags: multithreading, lazarus

I'm developping a multithread application using Lazarus. As i know, i have to add the class "cthreads" to uses clause, and define it in "ifdef usesCthreads", so here is the relevant part of the code:

```
unit Unit2; 
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$IFDEF usesCthreads}
Cthreads;
{$ENDIF}
interface
uses Forms, Classes, SysUtils, SyncObjs, Math, IdHttp,DateUtils,Dialogs,
ComCtrls, IdHashMessageDigest,idHash,IdComponent, cthreads;
```

There was no compilation error, but the form is not created because I'm having this message right after compilation: 'Run Error(211)' , plus the assembly window is showing: Cthreads_init(127).
I guess something is wrong with my code, so what is it?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Not sure but for multi-thread apps on Linux {$define UseCThreads} is must.

Comment: Add to project code immediately after `uses`: `{$IfDef LINUX}{$Define UseCThreads}{$EndIf}`

Comment: Instead, I had to add this to my project code: {$DEFINE UseCThreads}
{$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
cthreads,
{$ENDIF}{$ENDIF} . Thanks for your assistance